# When I use "currentIndex()" on

Tags: python, pyqt5

I've been stuck on a school assignment for hours because of this one problem. I need to check the index number (AS AN INTEGER) for the currently selected item in a ListWidget.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QListView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import Ui_countries

class MyForm(QMainWindow, Ui_countries.Ui_mainWindow):
    # DON'T TOUCH!
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
    # END DON'T TOUCH

        # EVENT HOOKS HERE
        self.countryList.itemClicked.connect(self.CountrySelected)
        self.actionLoad_Countries.triggered.connect(self.LoadCountries)
        self.sqUnits.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.SqUnits)
        #self.updatePopulation.itemClicked.connect(self.updateMemory)

    # RESPONSES HERE    


   # def updateMemory(self):



    def LoadCountries(self):
        global namelist
        global populationlist
        global arealist
        namelist = []
        populationlist = []
        arealist = []

        objFile = open("GUI/countries.txt")

        for line in objFile:
            line = line.replace("\n","")
            lineList = line.split(",")
            self.countryList.addItem(lineList[0])  
            namelist.append(lineList[0])
            populationlist.append(lineList[1])
            arealist.append(lineList[2])
        objFile.close()

    def CountrySelected(self,selectedCountryIndex):

        QMessageBox.information(self,"Country changed!",selectedCountryIndex.text())
        strCountryName = selectedCountryIndex.text()
        strCountryName = strCountryName.replace(" ", "_")
        imagePixmap = QPixmap(f"GUI/Flags/{strCountryName}")
        strCountryName = strCountryName.replace("_", " ")
        self.lblCountryName.setText(strCountryName)
        self.flag.setPixmap(imagePixmap)
        self.flag.resize(imagePixmap.width(),imagePixmap.height())
        idx = self.countryList.currentIndex()
        # self.populationbox.setText(populationlist[idx])
        # selectedCountryIndex.index()
        #^^^^^^^^^^^ useful code

        print(int(strCountryName))

    def SqUnits(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self,"Event Received","Please convert between different units.")
        if self.sqUnits.currentText() == "Sq. Miles":
            self.totalareabox.setText("YAAAAA")
        else:
            self.totalareabox.setText("YEEEE")

# DON'T TOUCH
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    the_form = MyForm()
    the_form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The area to focus on would be the CountrySelected function. Whenever I try to run `idx = self.countryList.currentIndex()`, instead of an integer, I get 'PyQt5.QtCore.QModelIndex object at 0x051A6470' if I try to print idx. My instructor wants us to use pyqt, and I have no experience with it, so I'm kinda freaking out!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, classmate sent me this: `index = self.listWidget.currentRow()`
No idea why index didn't work, but alas, tis the nature of doing your assignments one hour before they're due.